# The change of variable.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I have a quetion to ask and i wish to find her an answer for it, so i would like to know if the change of variables must to be a one to one transformation, if that the case i would like to know why. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are interested in, but if you want to know whether the equality$$\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_a^bf\bigl(g(x)\bigr)g'(x)\,\mathrm dx\tag1$$depends upon $g$ being injective, then answer is negative. The equality $(1)$ holds as long as:

- $f$ is continuous;
- $g$ is differentiable;
- $g'$ is continuous;
- $g\bigl([a,b]\bigr)\subset D_f$.

Actually, $(1)$ follows from the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of Calculus.

Comment: so in general the transformation g mustn't be bijective?

Comment: @AmineElBouzidi I would rather say that it doesn't have to be injective.

Comment: ok thank you sir for your answer.